# What do the parameters of the Dialog.Show method do?

Tags: .net, excel-interop

The Excel Interop library has a `Dialog.Show` method with 30 optional parameters. However, Microsoft's official (un)documentation is completely unhelpful (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.dialog.show.aspx). The parameters are labeled `Arg1` to `Arg30`, and don't have any xml documentation so I really don't have anything to go by.

How can I determine what each of these parameters do?

An example usage of the method is:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelDialogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application excel = new Application();
            excel.Workbooks.Add();
            Dialog saveAsDialog = excel.Dialogs[XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveAs];
            saveAsDialog.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and looked at the Dev Reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834620(v=office.15).aspx),

In the remark section of that page it mentions that if you pass the Build in Parameters available for the Dialog that you need from that page:

> For some built-in dialog boxes (the Open dialog box, for example), you
>   can set initial values using arg1, arg2, ..., arg30. To find the
>   arguments to set, locate the corresponding dialog box constant in
>   Built-In Dialog Box Argument Lists. For example, search for the
>   xlDialogOpen constant to find the arguments for the Open dialog box.
>   For more information about built-in dialog boxes, see the Dialogs
>   collection.

And here is the long [Built-In Dialog Box Arguments List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838781(v=office.15).aspx), it seems just to use the ones you pass, not sure if the order is important you will need to test that.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any better descriptions of what each parameter does besides the brief name? This is probably enough to figure it out, but names like `write_res_pwd` are still pretty cryptic

Comment: Where did you get that parameter

Comment: From the Built-In Dialog Box Arguments List. That one in particular is from the `xlDialogSaveAs` Dialog Box, but I was just using it as an example.